# Не возвращается json

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, json

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему на этой [страничке](http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/search_mysql_json) после нажатия кнопки формы не происходит вывод `json`-данных?

Вот код, если открывать страничку лень

```
          $(function(){
        $('#btn_search').on('click', function(event){
            var data;

            event = event || window.event;
            event.preventDefault();

            $.get( "search.php", {}, success, "json" );             
        });

        function success(dat) {
            $('#results').text(dat.heading + '<br / >');

            alert(dat.to);
            alert(dat.from);
            alert(dat.heading);
            alert(dat.body);
        }

      });
```

Answer (score 2):

json у вас не валидный. должны быть кавычки для ключей. и кавычки двойные притом. http://json.parser.online.fr/

Answer (score 0):

Вот, что возвращает запрос к скрипту:

```
{to:'Tove',from:'Jani',heading:'Reminder',body:'Don\'t forget me this weekend!'}
```

Comment: я тоже вижу этот через firebug. но почему не выводится этот объект?